# Do kidney donors eventually undergo glomerular hypertrophy in their kidneys?

Tags: renal, kidney-disease, organ-transplant, organ-damage, glomerular-filtration-grf

Quoting a line from Robbins and Cotran Pathology,

> "Renal ablation FSGS, a secondary form of FSGS occurs as a complication of glomerular and non glomerular diseases...striking examples include unilateral agenesis"

Well since unilateral agenesis is akin to having a single functioning kidney, does it not make sanse that some of the remainging glomeruli overtime will have to undergo hypertrophy and eventually sclerose?

Does that happen? I'd love to be pointed towards the literature on this if possible.

Answer (score 6):

This might be a bit delayed but this 2016 study on 29 kidney donors might be worth a read:

"In healthy kidney donors, compensatory hypertrophy of the remaining kidney occurs in 79.3% of the patients, with an average increment of about 22.4%. Older patients may have a blunted compensatory hypertrophy response after surgery."

Interestingly, the change in kidney size was not associated with any other examined factors such as a history of high blood pressure or the surgical approach used. However, the hypertrophy was less pronounced with increasing donor age. This may suggest that younger, healthier donors are more likely to develop unilateral renal hypertrophy following nephrectomy.

Study link: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27234720